# Adding commands to TextMate's LaTeX bundle

Tags: latex, textmate

I wish to add a host of commands (e.g., `\enquote`) to TextMate's LaTeX bundle. I wish to do that both for correct colour highlighting and for auto-completion (with the Esc or Tab key).

Where is the list of accepted LaTeX commands in TextMate? I've checked the LaTeX bundle, but haven't found it yet.

(When using other editors, e.g., WinEdt, that was a quite straightforward procedure; but I haven't been able to manage that in TextMate.)

Comment: Does the [TextMate manual on **Bundles**](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles) help?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Werner. I found it here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/latex.config
```

Comment: However this only handles autocompletion, not syntax highlighting...